# undefined reference to IID_ImageList

Tags: windows, qt, winapi, mingw

I use Qt 5.4 & MinGW.
I read that one should link uuid library to avoid this error. In my .pro file I added

```
LIBS += libuuid libole32 liboleaut32
```

However, I get undefined reference error anyway even if I have this line

```
D:\Dev\HinstStart\FileListData.cpp:74: ошибка: undefined reference to `IID_IImageList'
```

---

P.S: If I add some non-existing lib like

```
LIBS += libuuid libole32 liboleaut32 liblol
```

then I get "cannot find -llol" error. This is how I know that my LIBS statement is not being ignored

Comment: Is it in `-lcomctl32`?

Comment: thanks; I tried that but **surprisingly** no

Comment: right now I have `LIBS += -luuid -lole32 -loleaut32 -lshell32 -lcomctl32` and I stil get undefined reference to IID_ImageList

Comment: I now suspect that the required thing is in comctl32 but the linker can't see it for some reason

Comment: Hm, I actually have a feeling it's not in MinGW at all... If you use MinGW-w64, you can file an issue on their issue tracker and they should be able to implement it.

Comment: Are you including `<CommCtrl.h>` ?

Comment: I include commctrl.h

Comment: About MinGW compiler: I use the MinGW compiler supplied with Qt installer. It has MinGW 491_32 32 bit; I didn't change any compiler setting

Comment: Should be defined in uuid. If it's missing define it in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The solution, when using MinGW-w64, is to include the header `#include <initguid.h>`, before including headers that contain COM identifiers such as `commoncontrols.h`, `mmdeviceapi.h`, `endpointvolume.h`.

```
#include <initguid.h>
#include <commoncontrols.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <endpointvolume.h>
```

The solution was found at [Undefined reference to CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator and IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31666420/10450137)