# Undefined reference to CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator and IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator

Tags: c, winapi, windows-7, com, mingw-w64

Trying to compile an example code using COM and CoCreateInstance() using MinGW-w64 in C fails.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <endpointvolume.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator;
extern const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator;

int main( void )
{
    CoInitialize( NULL );

    LPVOID device = NULL;
    const HRESULT ok = CoCreateInstance(    &CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL, 
                                            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, &IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator, 
                                            &device );  
    CoUninitialize();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiling with: gcc main.c libole32.a  -Wall -Wextra -o a

Even though CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator is defined in mmdeviceapi.h it isn't found. Actually removing my extern definitions from the sample code gives the same result since both externs seems to be defined in the mmdeviceapi.h

When I was using __uuidof and compiling with g++ the code worked, but this C "replacement" for __uuidof doesn't.

Why aren't COM identifiers found?

Comment: Try `-luuid`. I do not know if the multimedia APIs you are using will be supported by anything that isn't bleeding-edge MinGW-w64 (and even then I don't know).

Comment: You defined them as `extern`, so compiler expects that you provide them somehow anyway. If you cannot link a `.lib` (`.a`), then define the static variables to the project (with respective `GUID` values).

Comment: @RomanR. Yes, I'm aware of that. I'm not asking how to obtain the actual values for the identifiers.

Comment: Think of `__uuidof` as getting you both `extern` and automatic static variable with value. In your code snippet you only do `extern` part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution, when using MinGW-w64, is to include the header `#include <initguid.h>`, before including headers that contain COM identifiers such as `mmdeviceapi.h`, `endpointvolue.h`.

Then no extra declarations are needed and identifiers can be used directly.

Solution:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <endpointvolume.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    CoInitialize( NULL );

    LPVOID device = NULL;
    const HRESULT ok = CoCreateInstance(    &CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL, 
                                            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, &IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator, 
                                            &device );  
    CoUninitialize();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```